# DynamoDB Stream in-ordering processing

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have following DynamoDB table with entries:

A B C // column

a1 b1 c1 // entry 1

a1 b2 c2 // entry 2

A is the key (partition key), B is the sort key (unique), C is an attribute.

I'd like to make sure the DynamoDB streams can guarantee in-ordering processing for B.

If changes made in this order - (note C updated 3 times)

{a1, b1, c1} => {a1, b1, c2} => {a1, b1, c3}

Can DynamoDB Stream guarantee the ordering?
Looks like in-order processing for updates on the same key is guaranteed. For this example, so the order of any update on a1 (key) will be preserved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the ordering is preserved because in DynamoDB all changes to items are made using the item key (whether partition-only, or composite) and DynamoDB Streams guarantee exactly once, in-order delivery of all mutations to each item.

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html):

> - Each stream record appears exactly once in the stream.
> - For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream
>     records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the
>     item.

Comment: How is this possible when multiple Lambdas are processing the stream?

Comment: in order processing only makes sense if you have a single consumer, or otherwise coordinate your consumers, so not sure what your real question is: DynamoDB guarantees that changes are streamed in order, exactly once -- how you consume them is up to you; saying that, even with lambda, concurrency is controlled by the number of shards which is controlled by the number of partitions so it's not really like you'd have multiple lambdas processing change to the same item

Comment: @aaa90210 If you need multiple consumers you will need to have a `modifiedAt` field in each record and only update the destination if the `modifiedAt` is later than the value at the given destination.

Comment: Keep in mind that since nov/2019, Lambda supports concurrent Lambda invocations via the [parallelization factor feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-aws-lambda-scaling-controls-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/). Lambda _"coordinates the consumers"_ so in-order processing is maintained. In other words, concurrency is controlled by the number of shards **and** the parallelization factor. However, Lambda ensures that **only one** Lambda function processes DynamoDB stream records of the same item (i.e. same stream record partition key) at any given time.

Comment: Good official article on this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-perform-ordered-data-replication-between-applications-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-streams/